# mysql syntax error when dealing with negative numbers

Tags: mysql, syntax

The MySQL Syntax Used

```
INSERT INTO friend_locations 
(user_id, lat, long) 
VALUES 
('82441', '28.665899', '-81.359756')
```

The MySQL Error Returned
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) VALUES ('82441', '28.665899', '-81.359756')' at line 1

I don't understand this

***UPDATE***

the syntax coloring on this site made ***long*** stand out, that must be my issue

Comment: Yep, also check what type of fields they are, lat should be a float(10,6) not an varchar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
(user_id, lat, long)
```

to

```
(user_id, lat, `long`)
```

since the word *long* is a reserved word.

I try (but don't always remember) to just wrap all of my field names in backticks so I don't have to worry about that sort of thing.

Comment: thanks I didnt know this, I notice that phpmyadmin does this when it does queries, I guess I confused the backticks with a regular ' instead of `

Comment: No problem.  Frederico also makes a good point about field types in his comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you quote your field-names with backticks, it ensures that MySQL doesn't confuse them with keywords:

```
INSERT INTO foo (`varchar`, `long`, bar) VALUES('zing', 2212323.02, 'yo mama!');
```

See MySQL docs on identifiers:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html